# Получить значение по индексу в enum

Tags: c++

Собственно есть enum:

```
enum DECK_COUNT {
    DECK_X1 = 1, DECK_X2 = DECK_X1 << 1, DECK_X3 = DECK_X2 << 1, DECK_X4 =
        DECK_X3 << 1
};
```

Есть ли возможность без лишних заморочек получить значение из перечисления по индексу?

Comment: не понимаю, чем вас обычный численный массив не устраивает вместо перечисления, у него как раз и есть оператор доступа по индексу []

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте enum'ы `START` и `END` - вот вам и индекс и границы цикла. Так делали в далёком прошлом.

И используйте `enum class`, enum - это пережитки прошлого.

```
enum class eShipType
{
    START,

    DESK_1,
    DESK_2,
    DESK_3,
    DESK_4,

    END,
};
eShipType getShipByIndex(const size_t index)
{
    return (index >= static_cast<int>(eShipType::START) && index <= static_cast<int>(eShipType::END))
        ? static_cast<eShipType>(static_cast<size_t>(eShipType::START) + index)
        : throw ExpectionOutOfRange("eShipType with index " +std::to_string(index) );
}
```

---

**Update**: так же отмечу, что случаи когда enum'у нужны явные значения очень очень редко - и как вы уже догодались типы кораблей для игры морской бой - не тот случай.

Comment: Супер. Спасибо.

Comment: Сомнительное удовольствие использовать `enum class`, который реализует запрет на неявное преобразование из типа перечисления в целый тип, и тут же орудовать явными `cast`ами.

Comment: @alexolut Здесь даже другая проблема имеется. Для данного перечисления в вопросе функция не верная, так как значения перечислителей не следуют по возрастанию друг за другом.

Answer (score 2):

Вы не можете перегрузить оператор индексирования для перечислений, так как этот оператор должен быть членом класса.

Но вы можете написать обычную функцию, которая возвращает нужный вам перечислитель.

Например,

```
#include <iostream>

enum DECK_COUNT {
    DECK_X1 = 1, DECK_X2 = DECK_X1 << 1, DECK_X3 = DECK_X2 << 1, DECK_X4 =
        DECK_X3 << 1
};

DECK_COUNT getDeck( size_t i )
{
    i %= 4;

    return static_cast<DECK_COUNT>( 1 << i );
}    

int main()
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) std::cout << getDeck( i ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
1
2
4
8
```